# How to add bean configuration file in an eclipse-based Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I started to work on a Spring project from scratch and while I was trying to add a new Spring bean configuration file, I just don't see it there. The project structure and the selection wizard is as following,

[image]

Figure: *No Spring section here in the selection wizard*

[image]
Figure: *project structure*

How to add a bean configuration file in the project ? I tried to get a template and add in the project. However, I don't see the different tabs (such as, mvc, context etc ) in the file page. The maven dependencies are fine and it's dynamic web project. I also tried with maven-archetype-webapp as starting point of the project.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-how-to-declare-a-bean-in-spring-application/ This tutorial includes the bean configuration file in a new folder "resources" declared in "Java Resources"

Comment: Install  `spring plugin` in `eclipse` to select the spring project from that wizard.

Comment: Use [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts). It is an Eclipse-based IDE customized for developing Spring applications. It provides a ready-to-use environment to implement, debug, run, and deploy your Spring applications, including integrations for Pivotal tc Server, Pivotal Cloud Foundry, Git, Maven, AspectJ, and comes on top of the latest Eclipse releases.

Answer (score 9):

1. Help > Eclipse market
2. Type spring and search
3. Find Spring IDE Roo Support and click install
4. Accept terms and click finish
5. Restart Eclipse
6. File > New > Others > Spring > Spring Bean configuration file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to provide a useful answer as well! Check out the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get your first badge.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it is showing a window which is asking to uninstall some features in eclipse and install Spring related thing. Does this affect other projects in my workspace?

Answer (score 1):

**1.Help > Eclipse market
2.Type spring and search
3.Find Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4 and click install
4.Accept terms and click finish
5.Restart Eclipse
6.File > New > Others > Spring > Spring Bean configuration file**

Answer (score 0):

- Go the Eclipse `MarketPlace` and search STS there
- Install Spring Tool Suit
- Then go to the window and select open perspective now you    will be
  able to see spring perspective there.
- After this right click    on the `src/main/resources`
- Click on new and select other and    search for spring configuration
  file
- Now you will see configuration    xml file select it and name it with
  xml extension .

Now you will be good to go.

Comment: It should be Spring Tools 3 Add-On for Spring Tools 4 instead of Spring tool suite