# Spring files doesn't appear in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a beans.xml but I could not find "spring beans configuration file"

[image]

when I try to install Spring IDE in Eclipse Marketplace, it doesn't appear there.

[image]
what is the reason ? and how to install spring IDE ?

I am beginner. Please tell me clearly

Comment: Have You tried official STS site?
https://spring.io/tools3/sts/

Comment: IMHO, beans.xml is old school, try using annotations.

Comment: is annotation method a common way ?

Answer (score 0):

sorry man, but actually i don't know how to use Spring in eclipse, but, you can use STS https://spring.io/tools.

STS have the same UI of eclipse, but work specifically of Spring.

Comment: STS had the same problem but appeared suddenly.
I don't know how is this happened

Comment: it may help you, im try to test here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369958/how-to-add-bean-configuration-file-in-an-eclipse-based-spring-project

Comment: i tried it but spring IDE doesn't appear in marketplace